# Get product Quantity in cart for every single product

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, cart, quantity

```
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $cartTotal =$cart->getGrandTotal();
    $cartItems = $cart->getAllItems();
            foreach ($cartItems as $item) 
            {
                $_product = $item->getProduct();
                $id=$_product->getId();
                $qty = $_product->getQty(); //get product Qty
                $image=$_product->getImageUrl();
            }
```

Comment: I wonder how can this question get upvotes it is not even a clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaibhav ,please use `getAllVisibleItems` instead  `getAllItems`

for getting no qty of a cart item you need to get using  getQty()

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$cartTotal =$cart->getGrandTotal();
$cartItems = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) 
{
    $_product = $item->getProduct();
    $id=$_product->getId();
    $qty =  $item->getQty(); //get item qty

}
```

For  getting `current product qty` , you need to load `product model by sku` then get `inventory` from stock object

```
$_producObject = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$item->getSku());
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_producObject);
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($stock->getData()); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: why down vote,Please explain?